# mouseover jquery method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

```
<div id="ob"><p>1</p></div>
<div id="ob"><p>2</p></div>
```

In my project I create similar elements with same id, dynamically using php.
My js is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ob").mousover(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

I have tried .live('mouseover',function(){}) also. But no result. What's the mistake? Why the function is not working?
[try this in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LH2be/6/)

Comment: also you've got a typo. It should be "mouseover" instead of "mousover"

Comment: The id should be unique buddy, use class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. jQuery not included - select jQuery version in the first select box in left panel of fiddler
2. ID must be unique - use class instead
3. live is removed in 1.9, use .on() instead
4. use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

So

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("p").click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });


    $(".ob1").on('mouseenter', function () {
        alert("mouseover");
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        alert("mouseout");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uyK8k/)

Answer (score 1):

Add JQuery lib file in your file,`Id` must be unique,use `on()` instead of `live()`

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("p").click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });


    $("#ob1").on('mouseover', function () { 
      alert("mouseover"); 
    })

    .on('mouseout', function () { 
      alert("mouseout");

    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LH2be/7/)